# How to prevent extra request if pdf requested refreshed in browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

ASP.NET MVC 4 controller returs pdf:

```
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{

    public ActionResult Pdf()  {

        byte[] result = CreatePDF();
        var ms = new MemoryStream(result);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }
 }
```

Results appears in Chrome browser window.
If this url is invoked or refresh button is pressed in browser, Chrome calls Pdf controller two times:

[image]

developer tools shows that second request is cancelled.

Pdf creation takes lot of time in controller.
How to force browser to send single request only ?
Or how to dedect fake request in controller and not generate pdf in this case ?

**Update**

page is defined as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="/css/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/Css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-et.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-et.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/plugins/jquery.jqgrid.showhidecolumnmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/plugins/jquery.contextmenu-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/plugins/jquery.createcontexmenufromnavigatorbuttons.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/myerp.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/TinyMCE/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/TinyMCE/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
   ...
</head>
<body>
   ...
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="_form" target="_blank" class='form-inline'>
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div id='contentCaptionDiv' class="panel-heading">
                        <input type="submit" id='_submit' class="btn btn-primary"
                               formaction='/Report/Html'
                               formtarget="_blank"
                               value='Show html' />

                        <input type="submit"
                               formaction='/Report/Pdf'
                               class="btn btn-info"
                               formtarget="_blank"
                               value='PDF' />
                        <input type="submit"
                               formaction='/Report/Xls'
                               class="btn btn-warning"
                               formtarget="_blank"
                               value='CSV' />
                        <input type="submit"
                               formaction='/Report/Designer?_entity=DokGReport&amp;_dokumnrs=130637'
                               formtarget="_blank"
                               class="btn btn--inverse"
                               value='Change' />
                        ...
                        <script>
                    $(function () {
                        var lastFocus = [];
                        var elements = getFocusableElements();
                        elements.focus(function () {
                            lastFocus = $(this);
                        });
                        $('#_form').keypress(function (e) {
                            if (enter(e)) {
                                $('#_submit').click();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                        $('#sendemail').click(function (e) {

                            $('#_form').attr('action', $(this).attr('formaction'))
                                 .attr('target', $(this).attr('formtarget'));
                        });



                        elements.eq(0).focus().select();

                        $('#_Report').dblclick(function () {
                            $('#_submit').click();
                        });


                        $('#_form').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function (e) {
                            var attr = this.getAttribute('formAction');
                            if (attr) {
                                this.form.action = attr;
                            }
                        });

                    });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you call Pdf action method? For example, button click or just a normal URL in browser.

Comment: Check out this article: http://rion.io/2013/02/24/prevent-repeated-requests-using-actionfilters-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @Win I updated question and added code used to Pdf call controller

Comment: Could you post the entire form tag and script that causes the post-back?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not try to do that. User may click refresh button as much as time they like. You should be checking whether the file is already created or not in your action method and return the result.

```
public ActionResult Pdf()  {

    byte[] result = GetExistingOrCreatePDF();
    var ms = new MemoryStream(result);
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
}
public byte[] GetExistingOrCreatePDF()
{
  //Check whether the PDF is already generated and exist in a DISK location. 
  // If yes, read it and return the byte array
  // else , create , store and return.
}
```

Comment: User clicks refresh button one time but Chrome sends two requests. pdf is created in memory and it does not in disk. Pdfs are documents and are created dynamically from database data. How to prevent or ignore duplicate Chrome request? Probably MemoryCache with small expiration can used but there is no need to send pdf for duplicate request so duplicate request should discarded

Comment: so you need to check your refresh button code to see why it is sending 2 request!

Comment: It also occurs on browser refresh: PDF is shown in browser tab. Browser refresh button is pressed if pdf tab is active. After pressing browser refresh button Chrome sends two reuqest, There is no user code in pdf tab, browser renders pdf there.